# Nginx Ingress Controller Docker image for ARM32 (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Is there a Nginx Ingress Controller Docker image available for ARM32, which will run on a Raspberry PI 3?

I have tried this:

```
$ docker run gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller:0.8.3
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Is there some documentation / list of images with more details on which tags available for the images on gcr.io/google_containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for arm64 was introduced with [0.9.0-beta.12](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/tag/nginx-0.9.0-beta.12). I don't believe there's an arm32 compatible release.

As for how to know which images or tags are available on gcr you can either run these:

```
gcloud container images list-tags [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]
gcloud container images list --repository=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]
```

Or just hit `http://[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]` with your browser, where for the nginx-controller it would be http://gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-ingress-controller

Comment: Ok, I guess I will look into using the Træfik ingress controller then.